# Aren't I allowed to override -sendEvent: in my NSApplication subclass?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplication

In my mac os x app, I subclass `NSApplication` and override it's `-sendEvent:` method. Apple complains :

> The app includes 'OBJC_IVAR_$_NSApplication._delegate' from the framework '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit'.

What can I do about that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code? Error messages aren't easy to decipher without any context...

Comment: There is no context ... The above 'error' is a complaint of Apple's support team. They accuse me of using private API, which is not true...

Comment: @Korion: No, Apple's support team does not personally write you messages every time you do a build. The message is from the compiler, and it has nothing to do with your override of `sendEvent:` (note that `sendEvent:` is not even mentioned in it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are accessing the application delegate by directly referring to the `_delegate` ivar, like this:

```
NSLog(@"my delegate = %p", _delegate);
```

You need to use the `delegate` accessor method, like this:

```
NSLog(@"my delegate = %p", self.delegate);
```

Comment: Wow, great answer! I wanted to add some code, but you got the answer :D.